# SQL Server doesn't recognize my parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got an ASP.NET MVC site with an admin page where I need to merge two records. I'm passing in two values, `@old` and `@new`. After adding those to my `SqlCommand` object, I call the `ExecuteNonQuery()`. This is generating an exception with the message saying

> stored procedure 'FixDuplicate' expects parameter '@old' which was
>   not supplied

As you can see below, I'm definitely adding the parameter. All 3 versions that I've tried are there.

What's wrong with this code?

**Version 1:** (please ignore the syntax of this one, I already removed this code, but I did try it and confirmed that the parameters existed when it reached the `ExecuteNonQuery()` call)

```
var sql = "FixDuplicate";

comm.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@old", model.Duplicate));
comm.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@new", model.Primary));

_dataAccessService.ExecuteSql(conn, comm);
```

**Version 2:**

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old", model.Duplicate);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new", model.Primary);
```

**Version 3:**

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@old", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
comm.Parameters[0].Value = model.Duplicate;
comm.Parameters.Add("@new", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
comm.Parameters[1].Value = model.Primary;
```

Lastly, here's the code in the `_dataAccessService.ExecuteSql(conn, comm)` call:

```
public void ExecuteSql(SqlConnection connection, SqlCommand command, bool closeConnection = true)
{
    if (connection == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("connection");

    if (command == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("command");

    try
    {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Open();

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (closeConnection)
                command.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Sorry, an error occurred ExecuteSql: " + ex.Message, ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (closeConnection)
            connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have confirmed that the values for both '@old' and '@new' are set when it gets to the `ExecuteNonQuery()` line.

**Edit:** Here's the full code, as it exists:

```
// Here we need to execute the "FixDuplicate" stored procedure
var sql = "FixDuplicate";
var conn = _dataAccessService.GetConnection("");
var comm = _dataAccessService.GetCommand(conn, sql, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

//comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old", model.DuplicateWrestler);
//comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new", model.PrimaryWrestler);
comm.Parameters.Add("@old", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
comm.Parameters[0].Value = model.DuplicateWrestler;
comm.Parameters.Add("@new", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
comm.Parameters[1].Value = model.PrimaryWrestler;

_dataAccessService.ExecuteSql(conn, comm);
```

Comment: have you thought about creating a helper class or a Custom Class of your own that passes in the parameters and adds them in a foreach loop I will post an example of what you could do

Comment: are you sure that model.Duplicate is not null?

Comment: @Salim yes, I added a "note" to the question...

Comment: once you add the parameter why don't you assign the value of its `@param` name by the actual name instead of indexing for example
`comm.Parameters["@old"].Value = model.DuplicateWrestler;` I think that you may also want to reference `MSDN SqlCommand.Parameters.Add` method  here [SqlCommand.Parameters.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @DJKRAZE Am I not calling the SqlCommand.Parameters.Add method already?

Comment: Yes but perhaps you do not understand what I have posted it's a Static Method that you can use that will save you the time and effort of manually adding the Command.Parameters.Add I would also suggest `ganders` that you seriously step thru the code and check to see what the balue of `model.DuplicateWrestler` is before executing the query..

Comment: I'd really like to know why there was a downvote, and also why someone marked this as close because "it's not a programming question", really?!?!

Comment: Run a SQL Profiler Trace and see what SQL is actually getting sent to the server.

Comment: I'll do the SQL profile trace when I get home tonight. In the meantime, I just traced the call via Fiddler and I'm getting 407's in my POST...that seems really odd.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `model.Duplicate` is `null`. In this case value of parameter **will not be set**.

If you need to pass `null` to `SqlParameter.Value`, use `DBNull.Value`.

See [SqlParameter.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference.

Comment: Nope, each time I set my breakpoints I confirmed that '@old' and '@new' were populated, and set to the correct values.

Comment: Just to confirm this (now that I'm at work and not sitting in front of my code). I just committed a check to ensure that both values are greater than 0. Once my cloud provider builds and deploys, I'll run again and make sure...

Comment: I added a check to see if model.Primary > 0 and model.Duplicate > 0 and it did not return a validation error.

Comment: perhaps you need to reconsider refactoring your logic.. you have some things that could use some serious clean up.. also don't be so defensive in regards to what others are suggesting.. for example I can almost be that the error is being caused because you are passing a null value when the database is expecting a non null value.. are you familiar with `null coalescing operator ??`when dealing with Database objects especially with Inserts or Updates for example you need to understand the `DBNULL.Value` and what it means in regards to how databases handle null param values...

Comment: also I would learn how to use the `using` construct as well as in your try catch{} why throw..??? you're losing the actual exception.. refactoring of this code would also help you in the long run.. but as it stands will not correct your current issue..

Comment: @DJKRAZE sorry, none of my responses were meant to be defensive. As I'm sure you can understand, when you work on something for a long time and you THINK it should work, it gets frustrating, especially with something as trivial as this. I've been doing development for 10 years, this is something that I learned year 1, which explains my frustration. I'd love to hear more on how it could be better refactored. I thought this was a decent pattern.

Comment: it could use some refactoring.. I've been at this coding for 20+ years neither here or there.. also I would just for kicks try using the parameter.AddwithValue method just to let the database handle resolving of the datatype that is being passed in by the param value.. this is a depricated method however still works in .net.. but this could help narrow down what the issue is.. also take a look at the StoredProcedure and make sure it's signature did not get changed

Comment: the only thing that I can seriously see which could be an issue 1 of the 2 parameters both being null values.. can you tell us what the values are..? also try hardcoding the values and running it and see if it works..if so then that will definitely lead you to the issue.. also in the database what is the exact datatype of `old`..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE good point, I'll try hard-coding to confirm. Right now I'm doing model validation and just checking that the values are greater than 0. I guess I assumed that since the model has it defined as int instead of int? that it couldn't be null...

Comment: that's why I was suggesting `NullCoalesce` which I am not sure if you are familiar with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx if it is null then you could always assign to something like `-1` for example I would try hardcoding the values first

Comment: so if the value is null then you could do something like this 
`comm.Parameters[0].Value = model.DuplicateWrestler ?? DBNULL.Value;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify a command type:

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Sorry, this is already there, I removed, what I thought was unnecessary lines of code. I'll update with the full version that is sitting in production right now...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check with Profiler if old parameter is set or not.
And also try to run this procedure from SQL Server Management Studio to be sure it's working fine.

Comment: I've been running the stored procedure directly from SSMS for months, I'm just now trying to add it into the app since I can't use SSMS from work (they block access to the Sql cloud provider). Good idea on Profiler, that will confirm that it probably [does not] exist. I'll have to try that when I get home.